# Salesforce Unable to Create a Library - Duplicate Name

Tags: apex

I have a library in **prod** org with a name as 'Library Internal'. When I'm trying to create a library with the same name in my **sandbox**, I get the error message as 'Another Library already has this name, Enter Unique Name'.

How can I create this library in my sandbox since I need to create it with exact same name as the one in prod?

Comment: If you go to the Files tab in the sandbox, the list of available Libraries is available. `Library Internal` may already be there

Comment: No there is no such a record available.